# jqGrid 4.3.2 inlineNav Add select el

Tags: jqgrid, inline-editing

I have an issue when the grid's Add functionality kicks in. My colModel defines some valid options for the select element. When faced with adding a new row to the grid, the select element is always rendering with an undefined value and not one of the actual values from the colModel. What is the technique to ensuring only the actual colModel values for this element are presented?

Comment: What is "the select element"? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I have a grid row. When editing it (initiated via dblClick) the form editing fields show up. The select element has a child option element with the text "undefined". Why?

Comment: Can you post your `colModel` definition? I would guess something is wrong with the configuration of the `editoptions`.

Comment: Ok.. pretty basic stuff for a colModel definition... the options are provided as a variable and do not contain anything undefined.

    {
    name: 'vendor',
    index: 'vendor',
    width: 240,
    editable: true,
    edittype: 'select',
    editoptions: vendorOptions,
    editrules: {required: true },
    sortable: true
    }

Comment: Yes but what is the value of `vendorOptions`? What are you setting it to? There are 3 different ways to do it as described here: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editable

Comment: The options are standard... 

`var vendorOptions = {value: "1:AAA;2:BBB;3:CCC;4:DDD;5:EEE;6:FFF;"};`

Comment: That contains a syntax mistake, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, you have a syntax mistake in your `editoptions` configuration:

```
Note the last element in the string - it should not end with ;
```

Therefore your `vendorOptions` value should be:

```
var vendorOptions = {value: "1:AAA;2:BBB;3:CCC;4:DDD;5:EEE;6:FFF"};
```

You can read the full docs here: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editable

Comment: Thanks... missed that pesky last semi-colon.